# in the postgres database {year1: value, year2: value}, how to output this data by columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, postgresql

in the postgres database {year1: value, year2: value}, how to output this data by columns in pandas

| year | value |
| --- | --- |
| year1 | value 1 |
| year2 | value 2 |

I can't figure out how to output it in tabular form.
when I upload to the data in pandas they are displayed as {year1: value, year2: value}

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxxxx')


query = "SELECT data_column FROM your_table;"
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)

# I assumed that the data is stored as a JSON string, you can normalize it
data_list = []
for item in df['data_column']:
    data_list.extend([{'year': k, 'value': v} for k, v in item.items()])

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

print(result_df)

result_df.to_sql('your_modified_table', engine, if_exists='replace')

print(result_df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can i then put this data back into the database, given that this is one of the indicators of the table, the rest of the indicators are ordinary numbers

Comment: You want to insert it in the same table or another table ?

Comment: I would like change data in pandas, and put it back tino postgres